# Simple Vue.Draggable inside nested ul list breaks during render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue.draggable

**Edit**

I tried creating a simple sandbox based on @Amaarrockz's feedback and the issue I'm having still seems to crop up:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="stepTitle in collections.stepTitles">
            {{ stepTitle.name }}
                <draggable tag="ol" v-model="collections.children">
                    <li v-for="child in collections.children">{{ child.step }}</li>
                </draggable>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
Vue.use('draggable');
var collection = {
    "stepTitles": [{
        "name": "Step 1",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Step 2",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "name": "Step 3",
        "id": 3
    }],
    "children": [{
            "parentID": 1,
            "step": "Child 1"
        },
        {
            "parentID": 2,
            "step": "Child 1"
        },
        {
            "parentID": 2,
            "step": "Child 2"
        },
        {
            "parentID": 2,
            "step": "Child 3"
        },
        {
            "parentID": 3,
            "step": "Child 1"
        },
        {
            "parentID": 3,
            "step": "Child 2"
        }
    ]
};
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        collections: collection
    }
});
```

The ultimate result I'd like should be:

- Step 1 *(Not draggable)*

  1. Child 1 *(Draggable)*
- Step 2 *(Not draggable)*

  1. Child 1 *(Draggable)*
  2. Child 2 *(Draggable)*
  3. Child 3 *(Draggable)*
- Step 3 *(Not draggable)*

  1. Child 1 *(Draggable)*
  2. Child 2 *(Draggable)*

where children should *only* extend to 1 level and be movable within their respective parents.

I've whittled it down to the fact that there seems to be an issue rendering a `<draggable>` inside a parent `<ul>`. If I make a 2 dimensional JSON array that uses the parent's `v-for` variable, like `stepTitle`, it comes with an error about `stepTitle is not defined`. If I make a 1 dimensional JSON array and use different `v-for` variables, it doesn't render the HTML correctly.

I've searched everywhere for examples with nested draggables but all the examples I find show the parent being draggable which isn't the result I'd like. In addition, the child was able to become a parent which is also not what I want.

The incorrect rendering tells me I've done something wrong, but does vue-draggable have issues with rendering children `<draggable>` inside a regular `<ul>`?

**Original Post**

I have an interesting problem when using vue.draggable that I've spent hours trying to figure out.

The general concept is that I have an array that contains a nested array. Here's the data:

```
"steps": [{
    "name": "Title 1",
    "steps": ["Sub step 1"]
}, {
    "name": "Title 2",
    "steps": ["Sub step 1", "Sub step 2", "Sub step 3"]
}, {
    "name": "Title 3",
    "steps": ["Sub step 1", "Sub step 2"]
}]
```

which should render something like this:
[image: Proper render]

The goal is to get those sub steps draggable and have the Vue array adjust accordingly. However when I introduced the `<draggable>` tag the code breaks with a:

> Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Here's the full code for context:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="steps-section-added">
    <li class="list-group" v-for="(item, index) in stepSections" :key="item.stepSectionTitle" v-on:remove="removeAddedStepSection(index)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="ist-group-item list-group-item-steps-header" style="display: table;width: 100%;">{{ item.stepSectionName }}
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success-white float-right d-flex justify-content-center align-content-between ml-2" v-on:click="removeAddedStepSection(index)"><span class="material-icons">delete</span></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success-white float-right d-flex justify-content-center align-content-between" v-on:click="editAddedStepSection(index)"><span class="material-icons">edit</span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <!-- Code breaks somewhere here-->
                    <draggable v-model="item.steps" tag="ol" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <li class="recipe-list-group-item list-group-item list-group-item-steps-body" v-for="t in item.steps">{{ t.stepText }}</li>
                    </draggable>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Vue app**

```
Vue.use('draggable');
var stepsVM = new Vue({
    el: '#step-section-ingredients',
    data: {
        steps: [],
        stepSections: [],
        stepSectionTitle: '',
        drag: false
    },
    methods: {
        addNewStep: function () {
            //
        },
        removeTextRow: function (index) {
            //
        },
        addNewStepSection: function () {
            //
        },
        removeAddedStepSection: function (index) {
            //
        },
        editAddedStepSection: function (index) {
            //
        }
    }
});
```

If I replace the `<draggable>` tag to an `<ol>` it renders correctly but the nested components aren't draggable. As soon as I introduce the draggable tag it breaks. From hours of experimenting I think the error is referring to the `v-for="t in item.steps">`. If this is the case, how do I get the `item.steps` to work?

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to get the subs draggable then you need to change the data structure

Comment: Even if I change the data to `"substeps": [{id: 0, stepText: "Sub step 1"}]` the code still seems to fail. Do you have a recommendation for what data structure would be better? I'm still a little stuck

Comment: no this change is not enough

Comment: @Amaarrockz I think I'm still a little confused, do I need to create an entirely new structure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your structure should be something like this

```
"steps": [{
    "name": "Step 1",
     id: 1,
     parentId: null
}, {
    "name": "Sub Step 1",
     id: 11,
     parentId: 1
}, {
    "name": "Sub Step 2",
     id: 12,
     parentId: 1
}, {
    "name": "Step 2",
     id: 2,
     parentId: null
}]
```

This is a one-dimension array but can extend upto n-levels. If you could maintain a structure like this then using vue-draggable you 'sub-step' from Step1 to Step2, based on the shift you just need to update your parentId's